# Loading inline content using fancybox in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I am trying to load inline content using Fancybox in a custom wordpress page template. The lightbox shows but is displaying the following error instead of the inline content.

The error: "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

Here is the javascript that I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[href="#contact"]').fancybox({
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.98,
                css: { 'background-color': '#fff' }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML which I want to display using the Fancybox.

```
<a href="#contact">Inline content over here.</a>
```

Please note that I am trying to get this done in a custom wordpress page template. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Fancybox are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version of the Fancybox. It's 2.1 IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change you HTML :

HTML:

```
 <a href="#contact">Inline content over here.</a>
 <div id="contact" style="display:none">Inline content over here</div>
    ​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fU54x/839/

If you want to keep the same html, and just display content from the `<a>` tag, you have to change the Lightbox script in this mode:

Same HTML:

```
<a href="#contact">Inline content over here.</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a[href="#contact"]').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
  $.fancybox({
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.98,
                css: { 'background-color': '#fff' }
            }
        },
      content: $this.html()
    });
});
```

I updated the example as well:

**Click here : http://jsfiddle.net/fU54x/840/**

Comment: I didn't know Fancybox would follow internal URL's. Nice! Mine works too, but your first example that doesn't require the `content` argument like mine does is cleaner IMO. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [content argument](http://fancybox.net/api) to Fancybox.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var inlineContent = $('#inlineContent').html();
    $('a[href="#contact"]').fancybox({
        content: inlineContent,
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.98,
                css: { 'background-color': '#fff' }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Markup:

```
<a href="#contact">Link</a>
<div id="inlineContent" style="display:none;">Inline content over here.</div>
```